# How to determine delay of sensor response after the stimulus event (with oscilloscope?)

Tags: sensor, oscilloscope, infrared, testing

I’d like to determine how long it takes a digital sensor to go low after the stimulus event (Ir break beam). I have no problem getting a trace from sensor: I can see it start to drop, the slope, bounce, etc. But how long after the stimulus am I seeing the sensor reaction?

Note that the stimulus is from a break of the beam, not a change in state of a pin.
Or is the oscilloscope the wrong tool?

Comment: What time scales/accuracy are you looking for in the measurement?

Comment: Could you substitute the mechanical beam break with an LED and pulse generator?

Comment: vir: Actually, I don't have a target resolution. I'm more curious and perplexed at how I could get that measueement. I'm hoping it is on the order of a 100us, but expecting more like a few ms.

Comment: Tim: That is an interesting idea. I'm not sure about the LED part, but the idea of setting up a stream of stimuli on the sensor that would be controlled by pin sounds like a big conceptual advance.

Comment: To avoid the xy problem: This project is an incline plane with track for little cars and Ir beam breaks that record to an array. Combined with another array of distances between sensors, the close-to-instantaneous speeds can be calculated. Works fine with 15 sensors 20 cm apart. But want to move to 100 sensors, 3cm apart. Am calculating the experimental uncertainty and want to see if the delay for sensor drop is significant factor. In actual experiment, I don't think matters since if they are all 1 ms delayed, and distances about equal, should just shift the timing equally for all intervals.

Comment: If all the delays are the same between the sensors, the absolute delay doesn't matter speed is deltaD/deltaT. Since you have multiple sensors (>2), You can check that the sensors all have the same delay by rearranging the positions of individual sensors and their distances.